# How to change icon on .exe using resource hacker when no icon option is available?

Tags: python, python-2.7, resources

I've written a program and then used py2exe to convert it to a .exe file. Now im trying to use Resource Hacker to change the icon but when i right click the .exe and use resource hacker all i see is the following:

A folder named PYTHONSCRIPT
and a folder named 24 and thats it.

does anyone know what the issue is here and how to solve it? I've read all the other questions about this and none of them have been a lot of help.

EDIT- Also any alternative way to change the icon on my python script .exe file is also appreciated so by all means if you know an alternative way show me the path!

Comment: I don't want to leave a link only answer, but this one is really just [read the docs](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons)

Comment: i never came across that link in all of my searching lol but thank you.